# Chaining a returned jQuery deferred object not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

So I have Form**Handler**.js which has function:

```
FormHelper.prototype.foldUnfoldForm = function($container, state) {
    main.addressDAO.get(debtorCasePath, viewEntityId).done(function(address) {
        return brite.display('case/' + state + 'AddressView', $container, address).done(function() {
            $container.children().unwrap();
        })
    });
};
```

brite.display does return a deferred object. If I console.log this whole code, it I can see it is a deferred object with all the methods (pipe, done, faile, etc).

In Form**Manager**.js, I just call the function in Form**Helper**:

```
FormManager.prototype.foldUnfoldForm = function($container, state) {
    return this.FormHelper.foldUnfoldForm($container, state);
};
```

My problem is that FormManager.prototype.foldUnfoldForm returns undefined. If I debug or console log to this point, the returned value is undefined. How can it be undefined if what I return in FormHelper.prototype.foldUnfoldForm is not undefined?

EDIT: The deferred object is actually returned before it has resolved, which makes it undefined in the functions that calls it. How do I avoid that and return the deferred object only when it is resolved? I am trying to do .done to the returned value, but it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined, because it is undefined...

Comment: What if you only return the deferred object: `return brite.display('case/' + state + 'AddressView', $container, address);` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff - shouldn't matter I think. Do you know what `this` really is, are both classes part of the same parent constructor ?

Comment: It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8NG8T/

Comment: "*The deferred object is actually returned before it has resolved, which makes it undefined in the functions that calls it."* that doesn't make any sense. if a deferred object is returned, it's a deferred object regardless of whether or not it is resolved.

Comment: @adeneo FormHelper is a member of FormManager

Comment: @KevinB If I console.log the whole return in FormHelper.prototype.foldUnfoldForm, it appears in the console after Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined, which means it's trying to use the deferred before it has even resolved.

Comment: show me in the fiddle, i don't understand what you're saying. It isn't undefined when i do what i think you're telling me to do. http://jsfiddle.net/8NG8T/1/

Comment: @Maxwell - nope, if it's undefined, it means you're not returning a deferred object, but undefined.

Comment: In FormManager, if I try to do this.FormHelper.foldUnfoldForm($container, state).done();, I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined, which means it's trying to use the deferred before it has even resolved.

Comment: **NO**, it means `this.FormHelper.foldUnfoldForm` returns undefined

Comment: That would mean you either didn't initialize FormHelper, or FormHelper's prototype doesn't have a foldUnfoldForm property.

Comment: If I console.log the returned value in this.FormHelper.foldUnfoldForm(), it is a deferred object, and it appears in my console after the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined, which means FormManger, is trying to use the returned value before it has resolved.

Comment: No, that's not what it means.

Comment: if you couldn't use a deferred object before it was resolved/failed, what could be the interrest to use a deferred object, doenst' make sense

Comment: Please show us a more complete sample of your code. Create a full working sample, similar to what i did in jsfiddle. The problem is not within the code you have shown us.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense lol, that's why I'm posting on here.

Comment: @Maxwell your issue is somewhere else

Comment: brite is a dependance, I don't know how it would work with jsfiddle

Comment: Make it up, just like i did. If you are 100% sure it returns a deferred object, then creating a dummy of that function that returns a deferred object is more than enough to represent it.

Comment: Nothing works, but please look at the **** and at the end of the console logs is the value I get. http://jsfiddle.net/57K8Y/

Comment: Believe me FormHelper is initialized and FormHelper has a property foldUnfoldForm

Comment: The console.log's parenthesis in the FormManager are not at the good place, bu you understand.

Comment: console.log around a return statement.... that doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: also, `**** return console.log(brite.display` is wrong. console.log returns undefined. I believe your debugging is breaking your code.

Comment: @KevinB why is **** return console.log(brite.display wrong?

Comment: Because console.log returns undefined? Try this in your console: `console.log("log value",console.log("hello world"));` You'll get `hello world`, and `log value undefined` instead of `log value hello world`

Comment: ?? I console.log() the value I get from FormHelper, I'm debugging, I know I should not return that. The problem is that what i get from FormHandler is undefined..

Comment: It's undefined because you are returning undefined with your debugging.

Comment: Oh yes, but I'm not doing the two console log at the same time, it's just to illustrate that the value I get in FormManager is not good

Comment: I see the problem. you can't return the return value of `bright.display` in the done callback of a promise object. the outside function has already returned by then. You can't return anything from the done callback of a promise/deferred object.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Do you mean I can't return the done() also?

Comment: you cant return inside of a .done. callback.

Comment: oh yes I get it, you are right

Comment: `main.addressDAO.get(...).done(function(address) { // you can't return inside of this`

Comment: I need to return the first deferred object!

Comment: Correct! Or, you can use .then rather than .done while still returning the first deferred object. What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Do I need to return both if I actualy still want to accomplish something after the second deferred object has resolved?

Comment: I'm going to go eat, post as an answer so I can accept. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return anything from the done callback of a promise object. Instead, you should use .then and return the original deferred from the function so that you will have a deferred object.

```
FormHelper.prototype.foldUnfoldForm = function($container, state) {
    return main.addressDAO.get(debtorCasePath, viewEntityId).then(function(address) {
        return brite.display('case/' + state + 'AddressView', $container, address).done(function() {
            $container.children().unwrap();
        })
    });
};
```

This assumes `main.addressDAO.get()` is returning a jquery promise object. If it isn't then we'll need to know what kind of promise/deferred object it is returning.